# portrait image from iOS renders landscape in browser on windows

Tags: android, html, ios, css

How on earth are you able to get around this...:

Two photo's taken on an iphone 6. One in portrait (the face with cup) and the other landscape (the box of eggs).

When the images are rendered in img tags in a browser on windows, the portrait image renders landscape. However, the same html renders the portrait image portrait in a browser on an apple device.

When you examine the properties of the two images in windows explorer  there is nothing that jumps out as an indication for the portrait rendering landscape in the browser on windows..? Coincidently, windows renders the preview in windows explorer correctly.. it just seems to be a browser in windows only issue.

I also tested this the other way around, portrait and landscape in from android rendered in img tags on apple and windows.. both were fine.

In the snippet below the images are being served in their original form as they were taken by the iphone.

```css
img{max-height: 200px;}
```

```html
<h2>Image taken in portait on iphone 6</h2>
<img src="http://www.beingyesterday.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/41de7162e3e0653f8a896ae82c2484cd5f19c1b9_1.jpeg"/>


<h2>Image taken in landscape on iphone 6</h2>
<img src="http://www.beingyesterday.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/ec7a1bd0088b5e5dd55b285c470aee14f4be2a43_1.jpeg"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some phones, including the iphone, are saving portrait images in landscape, and just adding an EXIF metadata to rotate the image.

The problem is this metadata is not consistently managed by all systems. Some are applying the transformation, some are apllying partially, others not.

The images on a website should never use this, and all images should be converted before:

- with your favourite image editor
- with your webserver at upload

Discover more here http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2012/07/28/exif-orientation-handling-is-a-ghetto/

edit: I see that you use Wordpress. The problem has tickets opened 6 years ago but all are closed or pending. However there is a plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-rotation-fixer/

Comment: @Kustolovoc, thanks for the detailed reply. I'm actually building a node js app with photo uploads. However I now know what questions to ask to find the right solution. Seems there are a few npm packages out there eg https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpegorientation   thankfully I don't think i have to think about png image correction.